# WPF&MVVM: Разметка textbox с валидацией и привязкой

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Хочу сделать валидацию ошибок при вводе данных в `texbox`. В уроках даётся такой простейший пример:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Но у меня уже есть привязка типа

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding name}"/>
```

которая уже работает и выполняет добавление объекта в коллекцию. Как следует выполнить разметку текстового поля, чтобы сохранить привязку?

Кстати, я не понимаю до конца разницы между `{Binding name}` и `<Binding Path="Name">`. Пожалуйста, включите это объяснение в ответ.

Comment: Ну а первый пример не работает что ли? Это тоже самое, просто расширенный вариант. Например, если нам надо на кнопке просто показать текст, то мы пишем `Content="Click me"`, а если нам нужно что-то большее, то мы используем расширенный синтаксис: `<Button><Button.Content><Grid>...</Grid></Button.Content></Button>`. Разницы никакой, просто расширенный синтаксис, когда простого уже не хватает.

Comment: @Андрей, я правильно понял, что `<Binding Path="Name">` и `<TextBox Text="{Binding name}"/>` - это одно и то же? Тут ведь ещё разница в том, к чему мы обращаемся: в первом случае это свойство модели, во втором - свойство `ViewModel`,

Comment: Откуда у окна доступ к модели? Эти две формы записи не прям в точности эквивалентны. Эквивалентны следующие формы записи: `<TextBox><TextBox.Text><Binding Path="Name"/></TextBox.Text></TextBox>` и `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>`, но у класса `Binding` есть [конструктор с параметром](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms597578(v=vs.110).aspx), который получает `path`, поэтому в кратком синтаксисе мы можем записать короче:  `<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>`

Comment: А, понял. Это я запутался, просто в этом [примере](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.php) нет шаблона MVVM и работа идёт напрямую с моделью.

Comment: Кстати, в привязке вы можете установить `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` чтобы валидация происходила по мере ввода, а не по уходу фокуса из контрола

Comment: @Андрей, ну смотрите: например, нужно ввести телефон (для простоты возьмём только 11-значные номера мобильных). Получается, что пока не будет введена одиннадцатая цифра, при вводе каждого символа будет сообщение о неверно введённых данных. Я правильно понял, что триггер здесь не подходит?

Comment: Вы прямо мессаджбокс показываете что ли? Там же штатно есть декоратор с красной рамочкой, ну и просто кнопку блокируйте. Например, в сеттерах свойств вызывайте ApplyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(), а при создании команды вторым параметром передайте метод для валидации

Comment: @Андрей, смутно понял, что надо делать... Не могли бы Вы в ответе привести пример с пояснением?

Comment: Для начала это почитайте: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level19/19_3.php

Comment: @Андрей, читаю. Сайт-то с вирусом!:) Я уже туда заходил, и как и в тот раз Avast предупреждает о трояне `JS:Miner-C`, причём с домена `coinhive.com`.

Comment: А, ну где-то слышал новость, что на professorweb майнер внедрен, но если блокировщик рекламы стоит - должен блокировать

Comment: @Андрей, внимательно прочитал статью. Первый вопрос - где следует хранить классы-наследники от `ValidationRule` в рамках паттерна `MVVM`? Если по логике, то в папке `Models`, так как только модель должна знать, каким условиям должны удовлетворять данные. Однако, в `MVVM` противопоказана непосредственная связь между модельню и View. Остаётся три варианта: папка `Views`, `ViewModels` и специальная папка для правил валидации.

Comment: Вопрос не простой. Однозначно только то, что в MVVM (в отличие от других паттернов семейства MVx) M и V между собой никак не взаимодействуют напрямую. Таким образом, правила валидации сосредоточены должны быть в VM, но если они сложны, VM может обращаться за валидацией в M (например, попытаться создать экземпляр сущности и поймать исключение)

Comment: В рамках паттера MVVM лучше IDataErrorInfo, а еще лучше INotifyDataErrorInfo. А размещение собственно валидации - кто в VM,кто в модели, кто внешние валидаторы.

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал @Andrey, формы записи `<TextBox><TextBox.Text><Binding Path="Name"/></TextBox.Text></TextBox>` и `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>` эквивалентны. Таким образом разметка

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

валидная.

`Name` - это свойство не только модели (в классе, описывающим сущность, такое свойство тоже должно быть), но и экземпляра, который попадает во `View` из `ViewModel`.